# Download error with youtube-dl and axel

Tags: video, download, limit, youtube-dl, axel

I am trying to download following video:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQWj2Fgxdrc
```

by combining 'youtube-dl' and 'axel'. I am trying to download this video in such a way that I want these two softwares (youtube-dl and axel) to not only save this video as "interview.mp4" but also limit download speed to 200KB. For this purpose, I used following command:

```
youtube-dl -f 22 -c -i --external-downloader /usr/bin/axel -o 'interview.mp4' -s 200000 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQWj2Fgxdrc
```

Here I am using following options:

> -f 22 for video format
>
> -c for resume download
>
> -i for ignore errors
>
> -o for output file name
>
> -s 200000 for limit download speed to 200KB

However, instead of downloading the video at 200KB and saving it as "interview.mp4", it is giving following error:

```
ERROR: fixed output name but more than one file to download
```

I have also tried following variation of command:

```
youtube-dl -f 22 -c -i --external-downloader /usr/bin/axel -s 200000 -o 'interview.mp4'  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQWj2Fgxdrc
```

and

```
youtube-dl -f 22 -c -i --external-downloader /usr/bin/axel -o 'interview.mp4' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQWj2Fgxdrc -s 200000
```

and

```
youtube-dl -f 22 -c -i -o 'interview.mp4' --external-downloader /usr/bin/axel -s 200000 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQWj2Fgxdrc
```

But still same error is appearing. However, if I remove the option (-s 200000), the error disappear and the video starts to download. But I want to use (-s 200000) option so that it should not eat all the bandwidth.
What mistake I am doing here?

Comment: Instead of `-o 'interview.mp4' -s 200000`, can you try `--external-downloader-args '-o interview.mp4 -s 200000'` ? If it works, I'll add it as a proper answer with some references.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved. The following command worked for me:

```
youtube-dl -f 22 -c -i \
    --external-downloader-args '-s 200000' \
    --external-downloader /usr/bin/axel \
    -o 'interview.mp4' \
    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQWj2Fgxdrc
```

Thanks to 'snowpine' at [linuxquestions.org](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/download-error-with-youtube-dl-and-axel-4175648542/#post5963619).